# Symfony2 - Intercept login to check if user is enabled

Tags: symfony

I've implemented my own activation mechanism where a user first has to confirm an email before he can login to the system. However what is best practice to intercept the login to check if the user is already activated?

I would like to simply make a check e.g.:

```
if (!$user->isEnabled())
    //TODO refuse login
```

Do i add a *onSecurityInteractiveLogin* listener? Or do i have to implement the whole login mechanism by myself?

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer and accept it.

Comment: For Symfony 4.1, you now need to use a custom Checker : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem by using the following interface:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface
```

and implemented the `isEnabled()` method.

If i now try to login using a non active user, it throws a `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException`.